# Very high error after full integer quantization of a regression network

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, regression, quantization

I have trained a fully connected neural network with one hidden layer of 64 nodes. I am testing with the [Medical Cost](https://www.kaggle.com/mirichoi0218/insurance) dataset. With the original precision model, the mean absolute error is 0.22063259780406952. With a model quantized to `float16` or `integer quantization with float fallback`, the difference between the original error and the low precision model's is never more than 0.1. However, if I do `full integer quantization`, the error shoots to unreasonable amounts. In this particular case, it jumps to nearly 60. I have no idea if this is a bug in TensorFlow, or if I'm using the APIs incorrectly or if this is a reasonable behavior after quantization. Any help is appreciated. The code showing the conversion and inference is shown below:

- Preprocessing

```py
import math
import pathlib
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing as pr
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

url = 'insurance.csv'
column_names = ["age", "sex", "bmi", "children", "smoker", "region", "charges"]

dataset = pd.read_csv(url, names=column_names, header=0, na_values='?')

dataset = dataset.dropna()  # Drop rows with missing values
dataset['sex'] = dataset['sex'].map({'female': 2, 'male': 1})
dataset['smoker'] = dataset['smoker'].map({'yes': 1, 'no': 0})

dataset = pd.get_dummies(dataset, prefix='', prefix_sep='', columns=['region'])

# this is a trick to convert a dataframe to 2d array, scale it and
# convert back to dataframe
scaled_np = pr.StandardScaler().fit_transform(dataset.values)
dataset = pd.DataFrame(scaled_np, index=dataset.index, columns=dataset.columns)
```

- Train and Test split

```py
train_dataset = dataset.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=0)
test_dataset = dataset.drop(train_dataset.index)

train_features = train_dataset.copy()
test_features = test_dataset.copy()

train_labels = train_features.pop('charges')
test_labels = test_features.pop('charges')
```

- Original model training

```py
def build_and_compile_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([
        layers.Dense(64,
                     activation='relu',
                     input_shape=(len(dataset.columns) - 1, )),
        layers.Dense(1)
    ])

    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))
    return model


dnn_model = build_and_compile_model()
dnn_model.summary()

dnn_model.fit(train_features,
              train_labels,
              validation_split=0.2,
              verbose=0,
              epochs=100)

print("Original error = {}".format(
    dnn_model.evaluate(test_features, test_labels, verbose=0)))
```

- Conversion to lower precision model

```py
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(dnn_model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]

def representative_data_gen():
    for input_value in tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
            train_features.astype('float32')).batch(1).take(100):
        yield [input_value]


converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen

# Full Integer Quantization
# Ensure that if any ops can't be quantized, the converter throws an error
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
# Set the input and output tensors to uint8 (APIs added in r2.3)
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8

tflite_model_quant = converter.convert()

dir_save = pathlib.Path(".")
file_save = dir_save / "model_16.tflite"
file_save.write_bytes(tflite_model_quant)
```

- Instantiate the TFLite model

```py
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=str(file_save))
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```

- Evaluate the lower precision model

```py
def evaluate_model(interpreter, test_images, test_labels):
    input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]
    input_index = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]["index"]
    output_index = interpreter.get_output_details()[0]["index"]

    # Run predictions on every image in the "test" dataset.
    prediction_digits = []
    for test_image in test_images:
        if input_details['dtype'] == np.uint8:
            input_scale, input_zero_point = input_details['quantization']
            test_image = test_image / input_scale + input_zero_point

        test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image,
                                    axis=0).astype(input_details['dtype'])
        interpreter.set_tensor(input_index, test_image)

        # Run inference.
        interpreter.invoke()

        output = interpreter.get_tensor(output_index)
        prediction_digits.append(output[0])


    filtered_labels, correct_digits = map(
        list,
        zip(*[(x, y) for x, y in zip(test_labels, prediction_digits)
              if not math.isnan(y)]))
    return mean_absolute_error(filtered_labels, correct_digits)

print(evaluate_model(interpreter, test_features[:].values, test_labels))
```

Comment: Look at possible values of float32 and int8. You can't be surprised that your error goes through the roof. One suggestion would be to trained your model directly in int8, but don't expect miracles.

Comment: @Lescurel So is it the expected behavior? I find that suspicious because as shown in this notebook https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/performance/post_training_integer_quant.ipynb, they observed almost no drop in accuracy after converting an MNIST network to UINT8.

Comment: They also have data that is uint8 by default (images), and their problem is one of classification, not regression. Yours is not. You will also try to predict values in a float format ('charges') that can go as high as 60 000 , with a model that can output only integer with a range between `[-127;128]`. It just cannot work.

Comment: @Lescurel That makes it clear. Thanks!

Comment: @SamvidMistry Are you able to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing quantization (*and machine learning in general*), you need to be careful at what your data looks like. Will applying a certain level of quantization make sense with the data you have?

In the case of a regression problem like yours, with ground truth in the range `[1121.8739;63770.42801]`, and some input data that is also in float, it is likely that training a model with that data, and then quantizing it in integer won't yield good results.

You trained the model to output values in the range `[1121.8739;63770.42801]`, and after quantization in int8, it will be able to output only in the range `[-127;128]`, without decimal points. Obviously, when you will compare the results of the quantized model with your ground-truth, the error will jump through the roof.

What can you do if you still want to apply quantization? You need to shift your data in the domain of the quantized set. In your case, convert your float32 data to int8 in a way they still make sense. You **will** see a big drop in performance in real use case. After all, with a regression problem, you shift from a domain of roughly **25 millions** possible output values (assuming a mantissa of 23 bits and 8 bits of exponents, see [Single Precision Floating Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) and  [How many floating-point numbers are in the interval [0,1]?](https://lemire.me/blog/2017/02/28/how-many-floating-point-numbers-are-in-the-interval-01/)), to a domain with **256** (2^8) possible outputs.

But a *really really **naive*** approach could be to apply the following transform :

```py
def scale_down_data(data):
  max_value = data.max()
  min_value = data.min()
  # normalizing between -128 and 127
  scaled_down = 255*((data-min_value)/(max_value-min_value)) -128
  return scaled_down.astype(np.int8)
```

In practice, it would be better to look at the distribution of your data, and do a transform that gives you more range where the data is denser. You also don't want to limit the range of your regression to the bounds of your training set. And you need to do that analysis for every input or output that is not in the quantized domain.